# ASP.NET with jQuery - POST vs GET

Tags: jquery, post, asp.net-3.5, get

Ok, I have a very silly question to ask (which Im rather embaressed about I must admit!). Im using the nyroModal plugin for jQuery within an ASP.NET 3.5 WebForms app.  Basically, let's say I have a hyperlink pointing to *http://www.mysite.com/GetData.html?id=100*

When the link is clicked, I want *GetData.html* to extract data from a database and populate some innerHTML elements with the return data.  the querystring value will be extrcated using jqURL plugin for jQuery, and I will use jQuery's built-in Ajax function to make a call to a webservice passing in the *id* as a parameter.

**My question is this**: How do I use jQuery.Ajax() if this is not a POST method, but rather a GET method, from how I understand it?  According to documentation, in order for $.ajax() to work, the type must be "POST".

Could someone please shed some light on this for me?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have many options:

1- use the load method:

```
$('#container').load(("/page");
```

2-use the get command:

```
$.get('/page')
```

3-use the ajax command:

```
$.ajax({
type:'GET',
url:'/page',
success:function() {
}
})
```

Comment: Yep, knew I was gonna feel silly asking this question! :)
Ok, maybe I need to do a little more reading up on this.  The impression I had (from a blog) was that you cannot return JSON data in ASP.NET if the type is not set to POST, which completely ruins the semantic definition of the HTTP verb IMO. Look, I DO have a lot more to understand, but could someone tell me - if I make a GET request to a w.service that is going to output paragraphs of text, what will it be returned as: JSON/XML/...?

Answer (score 2):

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "test.js",
  dataType: "script"
});
```

... from the [first example](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#examples) in the jQuery docs.

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.get()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.get#urldatacallbacktype) ?